# Getting Top/Right values ​from a css-animated element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the Top and Right values from an element being rotated by a CSS animation, for this I am using the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="ball1"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

#ball1 {
    transform-origin: center right;
    animation: spin 2.5s linear 0s infinite forwards;

    position: relative;
    background-color: #7883f7;
    width: 10;
    height: 10;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("ball1"), null).top);

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("ball1"), null).right);
```

However it returns a value of 0px, I wanted to get the value from Right and Top as if I was manually setting them (and not by the transform animation).

If this is not possible, is there a way to simulate a "circle" rotation and return the right/top values without using the transform?

ie:
https://66.media.tumblr.com/fb22b61bcbca3785a515e86c2276451b/tumblr_inline_pmimnjEvbK1v6q8wn_1280.gif?fbclid=IwAR2zjgE0hfB8emWOg0f6TOcQb8DWGbEvu9IQOr92fMq4HmMKjiAQRQzLmI0

Comment: `transform` does not change `top` and `right` properties. Why do you need them?

Comment: @KoshVery Actually I was trying to reproduce this gif I posted above, copying the top, right, and left values ​​to another div style...

Comment: Read through this -> https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/

Comment: @Salatiel, imho, CSS transforms is not a very good approach for your problem. I'd suggest looking at `canvas`, `WebGL` or `SVG` ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```js
const ball = document.getElementById("ball");
setInterval(() => {
  const rect = ball.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(rect.top, rect.right);
}, 300);
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}

#ball {
  transform-origin: center right;
  animation: spin 2.5s linear 0s infinite forwards;
  
  position: relative;
  background-color: #7883f7;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximation using `top`/`left`. The trick is to animate each property individually alternating the ease function to simulate the circular path:

```css
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
} 
#ball1 {
  animation: 
    Atop 2.5s infinite,
    Aleft 2.5s infinite;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7883f7;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes Atop {
  0%,50%,100% {
    top:50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    top:0%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  75% {
    top:100%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  
}
@keyframes Aleft {
  0%,100% {
    left:0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  25%,75% {
    left:50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  50% {
    left:100%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div id="ball1"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
getComputedStyle(window.ball1).top
```